# Login с помощью html agility pack

Tags: c#, htmlagilitypack

Не мог залогиниться с помощью html agility pack

Вот мой код. Сначала гружу страницу, потом ввожу свои данные в поле логина и пароля, а как нажать sumbit?
Вот такое не прокатит  -- doc.GetElementById("submit_signin").Click();

```
    HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
        HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = web.Load("https://steamcommunity.com/login/home/?goto=market%2Flistings%2F570%2FInscribed+Blades+of+Voth+Domosh");

        doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("username").SetAttributeValue("value", "crazy");
        doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("password").SetAttributeValue("value", "12345");
```

Comment: "Неверный логин или пароль." пришли корректные креды )) 

можно так, как ты предложил, а можно `WebRequest ` отправить

Comment: Да, данные не верны,  zziimm89;1234567890aAC

Попробуйте так

Comment: и как потом записать результат в переменную string

Comment: А почему бы не использовать официальный API?

Comment: Не шарю где его взять, как с ним работать

Comment: AngleSharp более удобен http://infostart.ru/public/466052/

Comment: уже есть пример http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20845146/steam-login-authentication-c-sharp

Comment: Там ничего не пойму

Comment: Есть еще идеи??

Comment: @Sergiy а что именно вам не понятно ?

Comment: Я не получил ответ на мой вопрос. Что в моем коде не так? То что вы предлагаете совершенно новый материал, который я пока что не могу понять

Comment: HtmlAgilityPack, так же как и AngleSharp, - это библиотеки для _парсинга_ html. С их помощью _невозможно_ куда-то залогиниться. С их помощью можно найти нужный элемент и изменить его значение. Но нельзя отправить данные.

Answer (score 0):

Во многих случаях проще работать с AngleSharp. В нем даже есть поддержка скриптов, но до конца недоделанная

https://github.com/AngleSharp/AngleSharp/blob/fe3eb2702c2da4cc9cb75c60fdc0fb8a68e13a18/src/AngleSharp.Core.Tests/Library/FormSubmit.cs

Пример отправки данных формы

```
public async Task PostUrlencodeNormal()
        {
            if (Helper.IsNetworkAvailable())
            {
                var url = BaseUrl + "PostUrlencodeNormal";
                var document = await LoadDocumentAsync(url);
                Assert.AreEqual(1, document.Forms.Length);
                var form = document.Forms[0] as HtmlFormElement;
                var name = form.Elements["Name"] as HtmlInputElement;
                var number = form.Elements["Number"] as HtmlInputElement;
                var isactive = form.Elements["IsActive"] as HtmlInputElement;
                Assert.IsNotNull(name);
                Assert.IsNotNull(number);
                Assert.IsNotNull(isactive);
                Assert.AreEqual("text", name.Type);
                Assert.AreEqual("number", number.Type);
                Assert.AreEqual("checkbox", isactive.Type);
                name.Value = "Test";
                number.Value = "1";
                isactive.IsChecked = true;
                var response = await form.SubmitAsync();
                Assert.IsNotNull(response);
                Assert.AreEqual("okay", response.Body.TextContent);
            }
        }
```