# Предложите что-то быстрее webbrowser c#

Tags: c#

Задача элементарная. У меня есть 10 ссылок, которые я должен спарсить, но обязательно нужно быть залогиненным на сайте. С помощью webbrowser проблем нет, 1 раз логинюсь и дальше оно запоминает логин\пароль. Только проблема в обработке ссылок. Дело в том что я не знаю как сделать чтобы у меня веббраузер обрабатывал ссылки не одну за другой, а все сразу. Как можно такое сделать? Если нельзя, можете скинуть пример другого парсинга. 
Парсить пытаюсь с https://steamcommunity.com

Есть что быстрее? И сможет ли оно запоминать логин пароль как веббраузер?

Comment: https://steamcommunity.com/dev?l=russian

Answer (score 6):

Стандартный компонент webbrowser основан на Internet Explorer, по сути, это он и есть, со всеми вытекающими последствиями.

Т.е. если вы хотите что-то иное, то скорее всего вам в приложении можно использовать другой движок. Но учтите, что другой движок и работает иначе.

По существу у вас выбор не очень большой - или использовать движок IE, или движок от FireFox, или Chrome. Конечно, можно поискать способ и прикрутить что-то еще экзотичное, но в массе именно эти три браузера. Я бы остановился на движке Chrome, или, для вашей задачи, использовал бы стандартный webbrowser.
Но раз с ним не очень получается, то если хотите, можете попробовать прикрутить иное.

Вот [есть статья](https://habrahabr.ru/post/170015/), где рассматривается несколько вариантов интеграции другого движка в C#. Автор статьи остановил свой выбор на [Awesomium](https://awesomium.codeplex.com/).

Но важно так же понимать, что движок браузера сам по себе - это одно, а то, что мы будем использовать в своем приложении — это некая прослойка (биндинг, wrapper, компонент) между нашим приложением и движком. Вот упомянутый Awesomium - и есть такой компонент. Но он - не единственный. Из неплохо себя зарекомендовавших есть, например, еще [CefSharp](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp), который, по моим наблюдениям, развивается более динамично, чем Awesomium.

Так же есть [WebKit.NET](http://webkitdotnet.sourceforge.net/), но насколько могу судить, он тоже давно не обновлялся. Есть статья с примерами о его использовании на практике. Она довольно объемная, потому оставлю лишь [ссылку на неё](https://habrahabr.ru/post/154917/).

Для WPF существует [A Real WPF WebBrowser](https://wpfchromium.codeplex.com/). Тоже давно не обновлялся вроде как.

Есть еще [Xilium.CefGlue](https://bitbucket.org/xilium/xilium.cefglue/overview).

[Open Webkit Sharp](https://code.google.com/archive/p/open-webkit-sharp/).

Существует вполне себе живой [GeckoFX](https://bitbucket.org/geckofx/geckofx-45.0) для движка от Mozilla.

В первой статье, на которую дал ссылку выше упоминается **xulrunner**, но, как я понимаю, проект совсем уж античен. Тем не менее, оставлю еще [ссылку на весьма древнюю статью](http://swblog.ru/articles/programming/brauzer-ot-mozilla-v-proekte-na-c.html) по его использованию в аж 2010 Visual Studio.

Наверняка, если поискать еще подробнее, то можно накопать и других компонент для интеграции движков браузера в свое приложение. Так что на абсолютное перечисление *всех* возможных компонент я и не претендую.

В любом случае, решать что именно использовать - исключительно вам.

**Что же касается самого вопроса как распарсить ссылки, то крайне рекомендую изменить ваш вопрос и привести в нём код, который вы используете для парсинга, а так же код, как пытаетесь обработать полученные ссылки, что вы хотите получить, и что же именно у вас не получается.**

Answer (score 1):

Можно использовать AngleSharp
Примеры можно посмотреть здесь
[https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/587807/login-%d1%81-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%be%d1%89%d1%8c%d1%8e-html-agility-pack](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/587807/login-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%89%D1%8C%D1%8E-html-agility-pack/587851#587851)

Пример правда на 1С [.Net в 1С. На примере использования HTTPClient,AngleSharp. Удобный парсинг сайтов с помощью библиотеки AngleSharp, в том числе с авторизацией аля JQuery с использованием CSS селекторов. Динамическая компиляция](http://infostart.ru/public/466196/)

[Примеры применения AngleSharp](https://github.com/AngleSharp/AngleSharp/wiki/Examples)

Посмотреть [обсуждение](https://github.com/AngleSharp/AngleSharp/issues/242)

Сейчас уже не помню ссылки, но вот пример поиска страницы с искомым элементом. Правда я там тестил и Scripting Api

```
string str = @"string WebsiteUrl = ""http://localhost:54361"";
            var configuration = Configuration.Default.WithDefaultLoader().WithCookies();
                var context = BrowsingContext.New(configuration);
                context.OpenAsync(WebsiteUrl).Wait();

               var elem=context.Active.QuerySelector<IHtmlAnchorElement>(""a.log-in"");
               if (elem==null) return context.Active.Body.InnerHtml;
               elem.Navigate().Wait();
                context.Active.QuerySelector<IHtmlFormElement>(""form"").Submit(new
                {
                    User = ""User"",
                    Password = ""secret""
                }).Wait();
            context.Active.QuerySelector<IHtmlAnchorElement>(""a.secret-link"").Navigate().Wait();

            return context.Active.QuerySelector(""p"").Text();
            ";

            string ИмяФайлаСборки = typeof(MainWindow).Assembly.Location;
            string Каталог = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(ИмяФайлаСборки);

            var scr = Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Scripting.ScriptOptions.Default
                .WithReferences(Каталог + @"\AngleSharp.dll")
                //  .WithReferences(typeof(Configuration).Assembly)
                .WithImports("System", "AngleSharp", "AngleSharp.Dom.Html", "AngleSharp.Extensions");

            var result = Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Scripting.CSharpScript.EvaluateAsync(str, scr).Result;
            textBoxEval.AppendText(result + Environment.NewLine);
        }
```